# How to Bubblesort using pointer?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am trying to clear up my concept in pointer. So I like to do a BubbleSort using pointer.The code I created  has an error in function calling. I could not find it .Can anyone help me please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void bubbleSort(int*, const int);
void swap(int*, int*);
int main(){
const int arraySize = 5;
int array[arraySize] = { 21, 56, 19, 77, 43 };

for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << array[i] << " ";

}
bubbleSort(array, arraySize);
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << array[i] << " ";


    return 0;
}


void bubbleSort(int *arr, const int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < s-1; j++)
            if (arr[j]>arr[j + 1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);


    }
}
void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int hold;
    hold = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = hold;
}
```

Comment: The compiler error you're getting is telling you that you forgot the `}` to end your `main()` function.  This is why it is common to indent your code logically.

Comment: ok thanks. Now it running but no desire output.It is just giving the un-arranged array

Comment: it does give the desired output. http://ideone.com/2FxOYa

Comment: If this is supposed be bubble sort using pointer, you could use *(arr+j) instead of arr[j], and arr+j instead of &(arr[j]).

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a } at the end of main

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: that is the cause of his error, he now has another error :)